# Computing $xyz$ divided by $xy$, where $x = 4, y = 2, z = 5$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm struggling on writing the expression. Since they're small number I don't think I'll struggle with the multiplying but I'm fairly new to expressions so I don't know how to write the expression.

Comment: I didn't really understand your question, does my answer help?

Comment: Oh you don't have enough rep to comment, please edit your post to better show what you mean, the edit button is below your algebra-precalculus tag.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\frac{xyz}{xy}$. Since we are multiplying these fractions together, we can rewrite this as $\frac{x}{x}\times\frac{y}{y}\times z$. Since any nonzero number divided by itself is equal to $1$, we have $1\times1\times z = z$. Thus we have $\frac{xyz}{xy} = z$, thus we can evaluate your expression by plugging in the value of $z$, which is $5$.